# WebView LoadURL and GetView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

I am use ListView and each cell is WebView.
So, I see that I must place WebView.loadURL 
directly in GetView! And it is calling every time
when I scrolling! So how can I cache WebView to call LoadURL only one time?
Or may be I would be save Inflated view in array and return
in GetView only view from array?

Comment: Even I using ViewHolder LoadURL operation is calling every time when I scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier for you (sorry if I am wrong) to make add layouts (example LinearLayout) and add it in a ScrollView instead. It is a bit of a walkaround, but if you are not using too many WebViews I think this would be much easier. Call it to load all URLs at onCreate and it will not load the page when you scroll.

This answear is an alternative, and I have read your question.